# Only map a set of specified values in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I've been wrestling with this small Clojure snippet for a while, but kept getting the feeling that there is a more idiomatic, simpler approach.

Desired behaviour; convert "1" -> true, "0" -> false. Else return the argument as is:

```
(= (mapper {:column 0} ["monkey" "stuff"]) "monkey")
(= (mapper {:column 0} ["1" "stuff"]) true)
(= (mapper {:column 0} ["0" "stuff"]) false)
```

This was my first attempt; a naive imperative approach:

```
(defn mapper 
  [attr-map row]
  (let [x (row (:column attr-map))
        y ({"1" true "0" false} x)]
    (if (nil? y) 
      x
      y)))
```

Second attempt:

```
(defn mapper 
  [attr-map row]
  ((comp #({"1" true "0" false} % %) row :column) attr-map))
```

Can anyone find a better solution?

Comment: Why not something simple like a cond or core.match?

Comment: Just a side comment: What's *imperative* about the first example?  To me, "imperative" means "using side effects".  (But I'm new to Clojure, so maybe I'm misunderstanding what the code does.) eg @dAni's solution isn't imperative.  `let` and `if` aren't imperative, for example.  "Functional" is used in one narrow sense to refer to methods that are common in functional programming.  I think you're asking for "functional style" ways of doing what you want--nothing wrong with that.  But the opposite of that style isn't "imperative", to my mind.  (`let` can be viewed as an anonymous function call.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the `:column` key is standard, you can use [destructuring](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--Binding%20Forms%20%28Destructuring%29).

```
(defn mapper [{c :column :or {c 0}}
              {item c}]
  ({"1" true "0" false} item item))
```

#### How it works:

```
({"1" true "0" false} item item)
```

Hashmaps can be treated as functions, whose first argument is a key, to retrieve a value. This form also accepts a second optional argument that is returned when the hashmap does not contain the key.

```
{c :column :or {c 0}}
```

This destructuring form uses `:column` as a key into the item passed into the first argument of the function. (In this case that is your `{:column 0}` hashmap.) The optional `:or` keyword allows for default values when the `:column` key does not exist, or the argument is not a valid collection (ex. nil, numbers, dates, etc). `c` will now contain either the value of the `:column` key, or the default value of 0.

```
{item c}
```

Since the collection passed as the second argument is indexable, you can use the same form used previously. The var named in the previous destructuring form, `c`, contains the value of `:column` and it can be used to index into the second argument, and assign the resulting value to `item`.

#### Code Golf:

If you can guarantee the input argument format, it can be further reduced to:

```
(fn [{i :column} {x i}] ({"1" true "0" false} x x))
```

Answer (score 3):

I would go for a more longer (and more readable?) implementation:

```
(defn mapper [{c :column} row]
    (let [v (row c)]
      (condp = v
             "1" true
             "0" false
             v)))
```